# Heroku:The page you were looking for doesn't exist No route matches [GET] "/"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm new to Rails. This question has been asked a lot but unfortunately none of the solutions provided have worked for me.

On Heroku, visiting the app URL after pushing my files with `git push heroku master` gives me the error:

**The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.**

Here's my log:

```
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796904+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-17 12:31:00] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796853+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796864+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/com
mands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796850+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in
 start'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796866+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:
17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796840+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-17 12:31:00] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796868+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796855+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.r
b:14:in `run'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796869+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796856+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in
`start'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796876+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-05-17 12:31:00] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796858+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/ser
ver.rb:69:in `start'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796944+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-05-17T12:31:00.796860+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/com
mands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-05-17T12:31:00.138102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-05-17T12:31:02.926026+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

I've also modified my `production.rb` by addding:

```
  #config/environments/production.rb
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Heroku also requires this to be false
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile=false
```

and here's my routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
exit
```

most of the code in this file is commented.

Please help?

Comment: Can you post your config/routes.rb? That might be the source of the issue.

Comment: I'm sure that there must already be a question with an answer to this laying around Stack Overflow somewhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

O.k. so after looking at the files you have, I do  not see any pages to view which means heroku has nothing to display.  First off I want to recommend the ruby on rails tutorial by Micheal Hartl.  You can find it free by googling "ruby on rails tutorial hartl", this will explain Ruby on rails better than I ever could, if you work through it and feel like it helped I believe you can donate some money for using it and I would recommend that because it is an amazing resource that I, and probably many others, have used to learn ruby on rails.

O.k. first why your code is not working.  You have root 'welcome#index' in routes.rb.  But there is no welcome_controller.rb with an 'index' action.  To create that from command line type (capitaliazation is important here)

```
 rails generate controller Welcome index
```

This will create an index page (the one you have in your routes file), it creates the view and the 'welcome' controller for it automatically. You can call the page anything you want but this will work for the code you already have in routes.rb. You will understand this more when you work through the tutorial.  This will also create a lot of files, again the tutorial will help you understand what all that is. I am only trying to solve the issue you posted about right here and stay on topic as best I can while getting you going in the right direction.

After that you will have to  push to git again and then push to heroku.  When you open heroku again it should land on that page, there will not be anything on the page other than a generic message, I think you should see something along the lines of "find me in app/views/welcome/index.rb"  If you see that your routing is working.

Comment: How do I determine the controller name and the page name?

Comment: Well what page are you trying to open and what controller has the action for it?  Just post all controllers you have and tell me what page you want it to land on first and I can give you the answer.  Is the code posted on github? if I could look at it there I could give you the answer as well, if it is just paste a link here.

Comment: O.k. so you have no pages to view in the app so when you open heroku it has nowhere to land.  I am going to edit my answer to give you  a page to land on this will be a long answer as it involves supplying a bunch of code.  I will give a tutorial recommendation as well in there.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thanks a bunch!! And I'm using Michael Hartl's tutorials coincidentally. It's just that his Heroku worked out of the box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53969/discussion-between-innentensai-and-rockwell-rice).