# Rails Heroku “The page you were looking for doesn’t exist.” after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am following a tutorial to build a contact manager app from http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/contact_manager.html

I am geting htis error message after deployment "The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved." The page is located at http://safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com/

here are the records from heroku logs

```
2014-08-01T21:21:56.962286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=1bf78c7b-2d92-467d-a655-f860501ec2ad fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=11 service=6 status=404 bytes=606
2014-08-01T21:21:57.255981+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=4f2708d7-ce66-435f-a636-a83272b146a6 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=5 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:21:57.566890+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=85a96d39-2a15-4a3e-859e-9d5ae0328169 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=10 service=32 status=404 bytes=606
2014-08-01T21:21:57.782291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=dcd61f4e-9033-4e9a-bbeb-8c3c6e199e91 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=6 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:22:34.256509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=6e960760-c293-4ff5-8ca7-f73e4629eb06 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=0 service=5 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:22:35.399376+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=017e319d-f1e6-467b-ae54-c0829f8ca160 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=5 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:22:35.811789+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=c0b4fdc9-161c-4bd5-be30-a3487f9aa43b fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=8 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:22:36.065855+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=21c9f5d5-57f2-4a64-a726-e4d54b18514b fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=4 service=8 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:22:36.273375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=cc1e9bac-b752-4a61-a745-50a66090b048 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=4 service=5 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:22:36.432949+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=b62e665c-e92e-4265-8aa0-44f478635b7b fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=6 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:22:36.985878+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=e41d514a-d19b-43a0-af16-3782c11c55f6 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=6 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:22:37.335984+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=ee9dd450-b9e2-4807-b581-75b183257866 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=5 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:22:54.942948+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by matif84@gmail.com
2014-08-01T21:22:59.384536+00:00 heroku[run.7383]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-01T21:22:59.427929+00:00 heroku[run.7383]: Awaiting client
2014-08-01T21:23:11.353244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=5e7e811a-350f-4a91-b9cc-b166dcf7c6d1 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=8 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:23:11.906902+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=5d75b2c6-c5eb-4ca7-bb33-9a0c4a213042 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=6 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:23:30.575232+00:00 heroku[run.7383]: Process exited with status 128
2014-08-01T21:23:29.430262+00:00 heroku[run.7383]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2014-08-01T21:23:30.590398+00:00 heroku[run.7383]: State changed from up to complete
2014-08-01T21:23:36.366280+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:setup` by matif84@gmail.com
2014-08-01T21:23:40.282474+00:00 heroku[run.6682]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-01T21:23:40.541404+00:00 heroku[run.6682]: Awaiting client
2014-08-01T21:24:00.075231+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by matif84@gmail.com
2014-08-01T21:24:04.213063+00:00 heroku[run.4882]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-01T21:24:04.222845+00:00 heroku[run.4882]: Awaiting client
2014-08-01T21:24:09.929723+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=54228362-bc47-4e17-8a6f-ecca99b93238 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=18 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:24:10.322375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=1e178a1e-5b3b-4289-a514-bf02f98a01c3 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=0 s
ervice=6 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:24:10.556592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=3ed57ba2-4c04-4f96-8aac-13b089cf2911 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=2 service=7 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:24:10.760255+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=8c1e7000-0027-4e51-8d26-5e2f6196c694 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=0 service=6 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:24:11.024884+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=aabd5863-fba3-4600-8cb1-b87c89c79d2f fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=6 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:24:11.205589+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=b678d050-a490-45e5-96f5-6c2bf2b7eb40 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1 service=11 status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-01T21:24:10.551580+00:00 heroku[run.6682]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2014-08-01T21:24:11.663950+00:00 heroku[run.6682]: State changed from up to complete
2014-08-01T21:24:11.652713+00:00 heroku[run.6682]: Process exited with status 128
2014-08-01T21:24:35.452736+00:00 heroku[run.4882]: State changed from up to complete
2014-08-01T21:24:34.226020+00:00 heroku[run.4882]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2014-08-01T21:24:35.451331+00:00 heroku[run.4882]: Process exited with status 128
2014-08-01T22:25:16.541175+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-08-01T22:25:16.542259+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107386+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-01 22:25:20] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107394+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `select'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107401+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:160:in `start'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107405+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:69:in `start'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107407+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107402+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:14:in `run'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107396+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:170:in `block in start'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107411+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107398+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107404+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:264:in `start'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107412+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107415+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107417+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107426+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-01 22:25:20] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107409+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107414+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-08-01T22:25:20.350762+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-08-01T22:25:20.350760+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-08-01T22:25:20.107424+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-01 22:25:20] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2014-08-01T22:25:20.350750+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-08-01T22:25:20.350758+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:5465
2014-08-01T22:25:20.350764+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-08-01T22:25:20.350766+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-08-01T22:25:19.441225+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-08-01T22:25:22.335578+0
0:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-08-02T00:54:44+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-08-02T00:55:13+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-08-02T00:55:13.134524+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 1be2800 by matif84@gmail.com
2014-08-02T00:55:13.134592+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by matif84@gmail.com
2014-08-02T00:55:19.453944+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-08-02T00:55:19.454198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2014-08-02T00:55:22.246658+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 42277 -e production`
2014-08-02T00:55:24.835901+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by matif84@gmail.com
2014-08-02T00:55:25.821524+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 00:55:25] INFO  ruby 2.0.0 (2014-05-08) [x86_64-linux]
2014-08-02T00:55:25.821474+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 00:55:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2014-08-02T00:55:25.821927+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-08-02 00:55:25] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2 port=42277
2014-08-02T00:55:26.056127+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-02T00:55:27.567255+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=83ab663f-09a9-49f3-9e14-a0ddde454b3d fwd="107.22.80.94" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=68ms status=404 bytes=405
2014-08-02T00:55:27.623070+00:00 heroku[run.2664]: Awaiting client
2014-08-02T00:55:27.851898+00:00 heroku[run.2664]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-02T00:55:58.710241+00:00 heroku[run.2664]: State changed from up to complete
2014-08-02T00:55:58.698719+00:00 heroku[run.2664]: Process exited with status 128
2014-08-02T00:55:57.624660+00:00 heroku[run.2664]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2014-08-02T00:56:59.143397+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=9476ae48-f809-442b-a4ec-b850eb555240 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=404 bytes=579
2014-08-02T00:57:11.235984+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by matif84@gmail.com
2014-08-02T00:57:15.136794+00:00 heroku[run.7352]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-02T00:57:19.065148+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=be2912f8-599b-4a28-ac88-cf328dcb4594 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-02T00:57:15.064777+00:00 heroku[run.7352]: Awaiting client
2014-08-02T00:57:45.067679+00:00 heroku[run.7352]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2014-08-02T00:57:46.602185+00:00 heroku[run.7352]: Process exited with status 128
2014-08-02T00:57:46.609525+00:00 heroku[run.7352]: State changed from up to complete
2014-08-02T00:58:05.331942+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=b6944792-411e-4dc1-8429-8620785b69a3 fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=605
2014-08-02T01:02:35.615565+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=1eea6666-37aa-487c-a6b2-42999ed2e5fc fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=579
2014-08-02T01:03:54.885182+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by matif84@gmail.com
2014-08-02T01:03:58.558256+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: State changed from starting to up
2014-08-02T01:03:58.496847+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: Awaiting client
2014-08-02T01:04:28.503140+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2014-08-02T01:04:29.625533+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: State changed from up to complete
2014-08-02T01:04:29.604536+00:00 heroku[run.7002]: Process exited with status 128
2014-08-02T01:05:13.427487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=5f07822d-ae0d-4fd9-b256-3707e8ba24ab fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=404 bytes=579
2014-08-02T01:08:57.349297+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com request_id=c87c547e-7163-4a0f-9ba0-4e3bfeefc61c fwd="198.105.46.47" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=166ms status=404 bytes=579
```

And here is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

here is routes.rb in my config file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :people
end
```

Comment: I believe you did not root a page yet, the error is telling you it is trying to find a route with "/" as its route name (which is the root route).  you need to have a root page to land on for heroku.  If you post your config file I can give you the exact answer of what to change it to otherwise you can look here an probably get your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711273/herokuthe-page-you-were-looking-for-doesnt-exist-no-route-matches-get/23727614#23727614

Comment: so if those are all the routes you have then I do not see any root page which heroku needs in order to land on initially.  What url do you want visitors to land on when they first come to your website?

Comment: You have a good point .This is my first time using heroku so i am not aware about it .It is surprising they havent mentioned anything about routes in the tutorial ! I want people to be directed to '/people' which on the local host is http://localhost:8080/people

Comment: the answer below should fix it

Comment: Thanks i made the changes to routes,rb and its ok now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is working if you go to http://safe-tundra-2124.herokuapp.com/people

You are missing the root route, add this to the routes.rb

```
root 'people#index'
```

Comment: Thanks,Anezio .You make it look simple and easy